# How do I resolve "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding"?

Tags: arduino-uno, debugging

Whenever I try to program my Arduino UNO Rev.3, I'm seeing the following error

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

When I plug this in, I do see a power light. There are no cables whatsoever connected other than the USB. I have another Arduino UNO which works fine when I upload the sketch (I'm using the basic blink sketch). How do I resolve this? What kind of problem can it be?

Comment: Make sure there are no wires connected to the Serial Interface (pin 0 and pin 1)

Comment: @KiraSan updated the question with more information (nothing plugged into 1 or 0).

Comment: I think you should consider using that Arduino Duo to reburn the bootloader of your Arduino UNO.

Comment: Also before doing that, make sure you selected AVR ISP as programmer, and chosen the right board.

Comment: i am also stuck with this kind of problem with my nano board....

Comment: Don't forget to try another USB cable. Also you can try to swap MCUs and try it again to figure out if it's board problem or bootloader problem...

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: D_Graeme solution is what worked for me (Nano, OSX). Here's a Stack Overflow question with many answers/solutions: [Arduino Sketch upload issue - avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19765037/1287812)

Answer (score 27):

After trying numerous suggestions, 2 different boards, 3 different cables on a WinXP and a Win7 machine, I finally got things working by going to "Tools -> Processors -> ATmega 328P Old Bootloader"

Comment: Although this answer would be correct for a Nano, this question is about an Uno and so your answer is off topic. We already have a question for that Nano problem: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/51771

Comment: For me it was the opposite: had to select nanoatmega328new on PlatformIO. Thanks dude

Comment: I'm using VS Code. Sadly, there is no "Tools" menu that I can find.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when working with Arduino IDE and XOD running on top of it.
What I found; looked like **baud rates were being set differently at different stages in the setup**. I compared Windows 'device settings', arduino IDE settings and XOD settings...and they are not the same and seem to change ? ...hence the 'avrdude:stk500_**** errors!

**To demonstrate**

Connect an Arduino board to a PC USB socket.

1. On Windows 7; Control Panel\ System and Security\System\ Device Manager... then double-click on 'Ports (COM & LPT)

   You should see FTDI

   or

   USB-SERIAL CH340(COM7) ... for a chinese serial com chip on the arduino board.
   Right-click on this and check 'Properties\ Port Settings' and note  the 'Bits per second' value : e.g. 57600 ... (write it down !)
2. Open the arduino IDE and click on File\Preferences and tick the option ;'**Show verbose output during: 'upload**'.Then close the 'Preferences' screen.
3. Load a small program that works. e.g. File\Examples\01.Blink
4. In the for your arduino board setup in the Arduino IDE;

   Tools\Board ... such as *Arduino Nano*

   Tools\Processor ... such as *ATmega328P*

   Tools\Port:COM7 for example ... make sure a tick is selected.

   Tools\Get Board Info ... will show info from the arduino serial chip (**a good sign your usb cable works!**)
5. On the IDE toolbar select;

   - 'Verify' and shortly it should show 'Done Compiling'
   - Click 'Upload' and the *Blink* program should load into the arduino chip.
6. Now here is the interesting observation; The 'verbose message at the bottom of the IDE screen will indicate what '**Overriding Baud Rate : XXXXX'** is being used! Write this number down next to the value you found on the Windows devices setting.
7. Now, if you are a XOD man, leave the arduino IDE running and run XOD.
8. Open the XOD IDE and open (Deploy) say the *01-hello* program and load it into your arduino board.
9. Select'welcome-xod' and select 01-hello program on left-side menu.
10. Select 'Deploy\Upload to Arduino ...'
11. select 'Board model:'  and 'Serial port:' ... eg COM7
12. Scroll up in the 'Deployment ' window and there will be another value labeled **'Overriding Baud Rate : e.g.115200'**

I HAVE FOUND THESE BAUD RATE SETTINGS CHANGE INEXPLICABLY !

I hope my observations will throw some light on your problem of erratic uploads.

Comment: Thanks Lionelb! What I had to do was go to Tools and change Port to COM3 instead of COM1, which was in use for a serial port on my system. This was after reading your solution and checking Control Panel\ System and Security\System\ Device Manager.. I did not happen to have an issue with the bits per second, but that is helpful too.

Comment: Thanks worked for me. After File\Preferences and ticking the option ;'Show verbose output during: 'upload'. I only needed to set the bits per second in the device manager for the used com.port.

Comment: To upload the program again I needed to change the baud rate to 9600 (after initially 57600)

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20735393/5507619

> I had this problem with a Crowduino, running the Arduino IDE on OSX.
>   The solution for me was to switch on verbose output during upload (in
>   the arduino IDE preferences pane).
>
> Then, when uploading, you can see avrdude sending three packets
>   avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] (with corresponding RX flashes on the
>   board) right before the avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not
>   responding error.
>
> The trick is to hit the reset button on the board immediately before
>   these three packets are sent. Then the program will be uploaded
>   successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had periodically encountered this as well and was stumped after I had tried all the recommended solutions I could find. In my particular case it turned out to be the cable I was using.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, however I was able to solve as follows,

- rebooting my computer
- or, changing the cable, basically switching between 2 USB cables (may be it just needed to unplug the USB and plug it in again).
- or, resetting the COM port

  1. closing the Arduino IDE
  2. disabling the COM port
  3. enabling the COM port
  4. opening the Arduino IDE

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a matter of `-B 10` instead of `-b xxxx`. So:

```
sudo ~/arduino-1.8.12/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -P /dev/ttyACM0 -B 10 -c arduino -p m328p -C ~/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -U eeprom:r:eeprom.hex:r
```